# How to append values to the beginning of variables in a makefile?

Tags: makefile

I have a folder called `code/` which has several `.cpp` files, that all need to be compiled into their `.o` versions and put in the `object/` folder. I'm having some problems with defining correct variable names...

First, I defined some paths:

```
OBJPATH=object#All compiled .o files need to be placed here.
CODEPATH=code#All .cpp and .hpp header files reside here.
```

Then, I try to extract all of the filenames from the CODEPATH:

```
SRC=$(wildcard $(CODEPATH)/*.cpp)
```

And then, SRC has a value along the lines of `code/A.cpp code/B.cpp code/C.cpp`. I want to get rid of the `code` prefix, end replace it with `$(OBJPATH)`, which evaluates to `object/`. I initially tried this:

```
TMP=$(SRC:.cpp=.o)
OBJ=$(TMP:$(CODEPATH)=$(OBJPATH))
```

But, as it turns out, that doesn't work because the `$(var:a=b)` functionality will only replace strings at the end of variables, not at arbitrary points.

If I could find a way to get rid of the `code/` prefix, my problems would be gone, so how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a pattern match substitution (that's probably not what GNU make calls them though):

```
OBJ=$(TMP:$(CODEPATH)/%=$(OBJPATH)/%)
```

You should also be able to do it in one step, without the intermediate `TMP`:

```
OBJ=$(SRC:$(CODEPATH)/%.cpp=$(OBJPATH)/%.o)
```